# How can I get all AWS Lambdas by Tag in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I have Lambdas with Tag of Name=production.

I would like to get them using Terraform, looking at [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_function), I can only get single lambda by function_name

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
   function_name = var.function_name
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources) to retrieve information for several AWS resources that don't have more specific data sources.

For your use case, considering `Name=production`, you can use:

```
data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "existing" {
  resource_type_filters = ["lambda:function"]
  tag_filter {
    key    = "Name"
    values = ["production"]
  }
}

output "arns" {
  value = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.existing.resource_tag_mapping_list.*.resource_arn
}
```

**Update**: as noted in a comment, the code above returns information from [`resource_tag_mapping_list`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources#resource_tag_mapping_list), which is mostly compliant information and ARN of resources. But you can pair that with a regular `aws_lambda_function` data source and using a `for_each` to retrieve all information from your Lambda functions:

```
# continuation of the code above
data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.existing.resource_tag_mapping_list.*.resource_arn)
  function_name = each.value
}

output "functions" {
  value = data.aws_lambda_function.existing.*
}

# example of information available with this data source
output "functions_runtime" {
  value = {for fn, result in data.aws_lambda_function.existing: fn => result.runtime}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this return only ARN of function? But anyway, this is still good answer and function to know about. Thanks.

Comment: Mostly, yeah. But you can mix with the original `aws_lambda_function` and a `for_each` to get all the details. I've updated the answer